# Can ffmpeg streaming jump to certain position?

Tags: ffmpeg, streaming

I am working with ffmpeg.

I can get a thumbnail from rtsp via command like below:

```
ffmpeg -itsoffset -4 -f rtsp -rtsp_transport tcp -i rtsp://fostv.com:554/test/smarttv_sample.ts.pac -vframes 1 -s 420x270 /home/guest/ffmpegsample.bmp
```

The problem is what I want is take thumbnail from position which I want.

If it is local file, I can do that with "-ss" option. How can I achieve this with a stream?

I want to take thumbnail from 10 minutes after video started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this in below way

```
ffmpeg -ss 600 -f rtsp -rtsp_transport tcp -i rtsp://fostv.com:554/test/smarttv_sample.ts.pac -vframes 1 -s 420x270 /home/guest/ffmpegsample.bmp
```

there was an easy way :-)

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to generate thumbnails at server side and transmit seperately. You can try to seek stream 10 minutes to future, however have in mind, that server need to have 10 minute feed storage at least and ability to seek a stream (as can ffserver):

> ffserver is a streaming server for both audio and video. It supports
>   several live feeds, streaming from files and time shifting on live
>   feeds (you can seek to positions in the past on each live feed,
>   provided you specify a big enough feed storage in ‘ffserver.conf’).

It basically depends on what server can do. I do not know exactly what parameter is (probably same -ss), but it seems that server itself must allow to seek 10 minutes to future for this to work.